# Notify sibling component of key down events

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have an `<input/>` which defines an `onKeyDown` prop which is fired when a key is pressed. In the callback, I check if the keycode matches a certain key (in this case, the up or down arrow keys).

I need to notify a sibling component that is in the same `render()` method as the `<input/>` whenever one of the matching keys is pressed.

Here is the relevant code:

```
handleKey(e) {
    let keyCode = e.keyCode;
    //Handle up arrow press.
    if (keyCode == 38) {
      console.log('up arrow pressed')
    }
    //Handle down arrow press.
    if (keyCode == 40) {
      console.log('down arrow pressed')
    }
}

render() {
    return (
      <div className="chat-input">
        {this.state.showCommandPopup && <CommandPopup input={this.state.inputValue}/> }
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
            <Input onKeyDown={this.handleKey.bind(this)} value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)} className="chat-input-comp" placeholder="Say something. You can use / to search, and . for commands." action='Send'/>
            //....
        </form>
      </div>
    );
}
```

How can I notify my `<CommandPopup/>` component whenever the up or down arrow key is pressed?

Comment: Save the key to state, pass it CommandPopup since re-render will happen after changing the state, if you don't block it.

Comment: Why you don't use the state for that? and pass the prop to `CommandPopup`. something like: `<CommandPopup keyUpPressed={this.state.keyUp} keyDownPressed={this.state.keyDown} />`

Comment: I am not concerned with the value of the key, only the event. For example, if I save the key to state, then pass the state to `<CommandPopup/>`, how would I detect 2 up arrow presses? The value would not change.

Comment: If you're only looking for Key up and down. The in your state you can have a counter, and pass that. And every time the other key is pressed reset count back to 0. I'm not sure, but I don't think there's a way to do what you want (which is passing event handler to sibling).

Comment: Do you want to know which key is pressed or how many time each key is pressed?

Comment: @DroidNoob I need to know which key is pressed and propagate that event. If the up arrow is pressed, the `<CommandPopup/>` should receive the event. Similarly, if the down arrow is pressed, it should also be notified.

Comment: @Armin That may work, though is sort of what I was hoping to avoid.

Answer (score 0):

Step 1.
You need to call setState inside handleKey() method. Once setState is called parent as well as child component will re-render.

```
handleKey(e) {
    let keyCode = e.keyCode;
    //Handle up arrow press.
    if (keyCode == 38) {
      this.setState({keyvalue:keyCode})
      console.log('up arrow pressed')
    }
    //Handle down arrow press.
    if (keyCode == 40) {
      console.log('down arrow pressed')
      this.setState({keyvalue:keyCode})
    }
//  It will call render() Method
}
```

Step 2.

Inside CommandPopup component you need to add, `componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)`.

Inside `componentWillReceiveProps(newProps),` you will get the updated value of `input={this.state.inputValue}`

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps){
  console.log(newProps.keyvalue,'keycode')
}
```

Comment: To notify your siblings you need to pass something to them. As you are passing input={this.state.inputvalue}, you just need to call setState and inside componentWillReceiveProps method of siblings you will get the value.

Comment: Ved, the `input` prop inside `<CommandPopup/>` is used to give the current input value from a sibling `<Input/>` component. This does not receive arrow key events. Please re-read my comment below the question.

Comment: Orbit, than pass any other prop to child component.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to raise an **event**, nothing prevents you to use js events. But I think you are not doing the proper way, since **react** is not an event base framework, and there is maybe a better solution to this problem using a state container like redux or mobx. 
On your `CommandPopup` component you just need to subscribe to the event.

```
class CommandPopup extends Component {
    componentDidMount() {
        window.addEventListener('keyUp', () => {
            console.log('Key UP ...');            
        });

        window.addEventListener('keyDown', () => {
            console.log('Key DOWN ....');            
        });
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>Something ...</div>
        );
    }

}
```

And just dispatch the event:

```
handleKey(e) {
    let keyCode = e.keyCode;
    //Handle up arrow press.
    if (keyCode == 38) {
      const ev = new Event('keyUp', { 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': false });
      document.dispatchEvent(ev);            
    }
    //Handle down arrow press.
    if (keyCode == 40) {
      const ev = new Event('keyDown', { 'bubbles': true, 'cancelable': false });
      document.dispatchEvent(ev);
    }
}

render() {  
    return (
      <div className="chat-input">
        {this.state.showCommandPopup && <CommandPopup input={this.state.inputValue}/> }
        <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit.bind(this)}>
            <Input onKeyDown={this.handleKey.bind(this)} value={this.state.inputValue} onChange={this.onInputChange.bind(this)} />
        </form>
      </div>
    );
}
```

Again maybe you should take a look to **mobx computed values**, this is the kind of problem they can solve. 
Hope this help.